# Call route from button inside an <a> tag laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm new in laravel and Javascript.

I have a route which looks like

```
Route::get('/problems/{problem}/edit', 'AdminController@editProblem');
```

and my page looks like
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdBA0.png)

HTML code for this page is

```
@foreach($in_contest->problems as $problem)
    <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-file fa-lg"></i>
            {{ $problem->title }}
            <span class="pull-right">
                <button onclick="callRoute()" class="btn btn-xs btn-info button">Edit</button>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I wrote javascript code for this onclick which is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callRoute() {
        window.location = '{{ url('/problems/' . $problem->id . '/edit') }}';
    }
</script>
```

now every time I'm clicking Edit button on P1, P2, or P3 its opening the edit page for P4. Same url is opening for all.
I want when I click edit on P1 its redirect to edit page for $problem-id with P1. and same for the others too.

What is the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is calling p4 is that after you have run your foreach loop, you are basically writing the last iteration of problem ID to your javascript.

You can avoid adding blade syntax to your javascript all together by changing your view code to the following so it passes the current problem ID to your javascript function

```
@foreach($in_contest->problems as $problem)
    <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-file fa-lg"></i>
            {{ $problem->title }}
            <span class="pull-right">
                <button onclick="callRoute({{ $problem->id }})" class="btn btn-xs btn-info button">Edit</button>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

and your javascript function to the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callRoute(problemID) {
        window.location = '/problems/' + problemID + '/edit';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Worked Like magic. @Rob Fonseca 
Now I have another question what if I want to pass the whole problem object. is it possible too ? Just wondering.. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There is a way. I would recommend an API call via AJAX to do it in a much cleaner manner (too much involved to explain here), but the down and dirty way is in your view, change {{ $problem->id }} to {{ json_encode($problem) }} and then your callRoute function would  change to   function callRoute(data) { var problem = JSON.parse(data); }. You can then reference all the properties of the problem object like problem.id, problem.title, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You've 4 results in your page and your `callRoute` function is outside of your loop so after the loop done it's job the variable `$problem` you are accessing in your script tag is the last one iterated over the results collection so that's why it's having the id 4

simply just write it like

```
<button onclick="callRoute({{ $problem->id }})" class="btn btn-xs btn-info button">Edit</button>
```

and in your script

```
function callRoute(problem_id) {
    window.location = '/problems/' + problem_id + '/edit';
}
```

Comment: Also a good answer. Was going to suggest he just changes to a <a> element as well and avoid javascript since it does nothing other than redirect.

Comment: I don't want to use an`<a>` tag, I want to use button, because `<a>` tag inside an `<a>` tag is not permitted. As my `list-group-item` itself an `<a>` tag so if I use another `<a>` inside it, first one is pushing the second one to outside of the `list-group-item'. which I don't want.
I don't want to use the design, Could you please refer some JavaScript which can solve the problem ?
There must be some way to handle this in js. I hope.

Comment: @mostafiz13 Why my answer is not accepted if it helped?

Comment: Sorry @Zayn Ali, rob gave the right ans before you. It worked and after that I saw you edited your answer too. and both of you gave the same thing. as he gave it earlier I accepted his one. As my reputation is not enough for giving up vote I can't gave you one. Maybe later I will definitely friend. Thanks. :)

Comment: Oh okay :), i received your comment that you don't want to use anchor tag so i edited my answer to use button and didn't saw above my answer that Rob had posted the same answer as mine. I'm glad that we both helped you. :) Cheers